# calling a method in an android fragment from the mainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment

Today I tried building my first own Android app.

I wanted to get a main activity which show a fragment (in my case it’s called “eingabeFragment”). This fragment contains a editText and a button. As soon as the button is pressed I want the “eingabeFragment” to disappear and a new “anzeigeFragment” to be shown.

Everything works fine so far. Now I want the text entered in the “eingabeFragment” to be shown in my “anzeigefragment”.

I tried to manage this with an interface in the “eingabefragment” which is implemented by the activity.

As soon as the button is pressed, the mainactivity fetches the text from the “eingabeFragment” by calling my getText method.

For debugging purposes I added a System.out.println to test my program. 
So I know, that this part works fine.

Now I thought I just have to add this String to a textview in my “anzeigeFragment”. Unfortunately the output is “Fragment not found”, what means that I get a Nullpointer when I call my “setInfo” method in my “anzeigenFragment”.

My question is how to access public methods in a fragment from the activity after this fragment replaced an old fragment.

AnzeigeFragment

```
package local.mydomain.versuch;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AnzeigeFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anzeige, container, false);


}

public void setInfo(String text)
{
    TextView az = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.output);
    az.setText(text);
}



}
```

EingabeFragment

```
package local.mydomain.versuch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class EingabeFragment extends Fragment {
public static String MESSAGE = "local.mydomain.versuch.MESSAGE";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eingabe, container, false);


}

public interface Clicked{
    public void pressed(View view);
}

public String getInfo()
{
    EditText et = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.eingabe);
    String result = et.getText().toString();
    return result;
}

}
```

and finally MainActivity

```
package local.mydomain.versuch;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   EingabeFragment.Clicked{

public static String MESSAGE = "local.mydomain.versuch.MESSAGE";
private EingabeFragment eingabeFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null)
    {
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    eingabeFragment = new EingabeFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            add(R.id.fragment_container,eingabeFragment, "Eingabe").commit();

}

@Override
public void pressed(View view) {

    EingabeFragment ef = (EingabeFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Eingabe");
    String info = ef.getInfo();

    System.out.println(info);

    AnzeigeFragment anzeigeFragment = new AnzeigeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, anzeigeFragment, "AnzeigeFrag");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();

    AnzeigeFragment az = (AnzeigeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("AnzeigeFrag");

    if (az==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Fragment not found");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Everything ok");
        az.setInfo(info);
    }

    System.out.println(info);
}
}
```

Any explanation will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate the message between your two fragment via bundle

Update your code something like this

> 

```
AnzeigeFragment anzeigeFragment = new AnzeigeFragment();

Bundle data=new Bundle()
Data.putStringExtra("messagekey","message value");

anzeigeFragment.setArguments(data);
> FragmentTransaction transaction=
> getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, anzeigeFragment,
> "AnzeigeFrag"); transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Further in your second fragment You can retrieve this data via calling **getArgument()** method of fragment.

And then getStringExtra("messagekey") method.